# Excel: Excluding first word

Tags: excel

How can I make a formula to exclude the first word and keep the second word. If the cell only has a single word it should be blank. See example below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",A1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1),0)>0,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the second word if there are two or more words, and blank if there is not, try:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))
```

Could there be more than two words?  What then?

Here is an approach that will always return the Last word (and blank if there is just one word):

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(" ",TRIM(A1)),TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))),"")
```